# Berkshelf downloads cookbooks from the net everytime

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, berkshelf

I am working on developing a cookbook for my application. I am using vagrant with chef solo. I have written the cookbook such that only my cookbook is referenced in the Berkfile like and other cookbook files are referenced in my cookbook

```
 cookbook "myapp", "=0.1.0", path: '/Users/test/work/apps/myapp-cookbook'
```

But every dependant cookbook now seems to download from the net everytime!
When I mentioned the cookbook directly this was not the case.
Any idea what I might have changed ?

```
[Berkshelf] Using postgresql (3.3.4)
[Berkshelf] Installing apt (2.3.8) from site: 'http://cookbooks.opscode.com/api/v1/cookbooks'
[Berkshelf] Using build-essential (1.4.4)
[Berkshelf] Using openssl (1.1.0)
[Berkshelf] Installing python (1.4.6) from site: 'http://cookbooks.opscode.com/api/v1/cookbooks'
[Berkshelf] Using yum-epel (0.3.4)
[Berkshelf] Using yum (3.1.2)
[Berkshelf] Installing mongodb (0.13.7) from site: 'http://cookbooks.opscode.com/api/v1/cookbooks'
[Berkshelf] Using runit (1.5.10)
[Berkshelf] Installing nginx (2.4.2) from site: 'http://cookbooks.opscode.com/api/v1/cookbooks'
[Berkshelf] Using bluepill (2.3.1)
[Berkshelf] Using rsyslog (1.12.2)
[Berkshelf] Using ohai (1.1.12)
```

**[Edit]**
When I add all the dependencies to the Berksfile directly does not seem to take the time to complete the run.

```
cookbook "apt", "=2.3.9", git: 'git@github.com:opscode-cookbooks/apt.git'
cookbook "python", "=1.4.7", git: 'git@github.com:poise/python.git'
cookbook "nginx", "=2.4.3", git: 'git@github.com:opscode-cookbooks/nginx.git'
cookbook "mongodb", "=0.15.0", git: 'git@github.com:edelight/chef-mongodb.git'
cookbook "postgresql", "=3.3.4", git: 'git@github.com:hw-cookbooks/postgresql.git'
cookbook "chef-solo-search", "=0.5.1", git: 'git@github.com:edelight/chef-solo-search.git'
```

Comment: What version of Berkshelf?

Comment: berkshelf (2.0.14) Interestingly when I added all the cookbooks as dependencies in Berksfile. Does not seem to take a long time.